# Shorter way to do: if (a !== undefined && a.b !== undefined && a.b.c === 'foo')

Tags: javascript, object, lodash

If I need to check an attribute of an object, and it's object (and so on) but can't be sure whether the object exists in the first place how can I make the condition simpler than this?

```
if (a !== undefined && a.b !== undefined && a.b.c === 'foo')
```

I'm also using **LoDash** if it has any meaningful function.

Comment: That code will throw an error when `a` doesn't exist. See my answer below for correct code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

if you know that `a` is in the current scope (like comming in as an argument) you can do
`if(a && a.b && a.b.c === 'foo')`
**but** if ther's an chance `a` is never defined you have to check the type like:
`if( typeof a != 'undefined' && a.b && a.b.c === 'foo')`

**update**
when using lodah the `has` function can give an better syntax (that unlike the `get` function returns true if the propperty is a falsy value. Thanks @ryeballar):

`if(lodash.has(a,'b.c')){
    console.log(a.b.c);
}`

Comment: `if(a && a.b && a.b.c === 'foo')` will throw an error when `a` doesn't exist.

Comment: @ScottMarcus: If `a` doesn't exist, it's a bug that should be resolved anyway, making the error message important. If `a` is a global that *can't* be known, then `window.a && a.b && a.b.c`.

Comment: @ScottMarcus you are right! i updated my anwser. thanks for picking up on it

Comment: @VeXii: Let's not casually bury our errors. If you're reading a variable that doesn't exist, the problem should be fixed, not hidden. The `typeof a !== "undefined"` syntax probably causes more problems, from obscured errors and simple typos getting the syntax wrong, than it solves.

Comment: @squint lets focus on what is being asked? the qustion is how do i shorten this null check.

Comment: @VeXii: At the expense of introducing potentially harmful patterns? I disagree. Your original answer was better, which was why I gave it +1. Not so sure now.

Comment: @squint we don't know the case.... there's a big chance the OP is inside an callback and just wanner check if the argument is containing an value, in witch case i told the person how deal with the question ad hand and not push my assumption's on them

Comment: Don't know what being in a callback has to do with anything. Doesn't change the fact that burying errors is a poor way of dealing with them.  I see only downsides to that technique. If you truly think errors should be hidden like that, then you might as well wrap your entire program in a `try/catch`. Just sayin'...

Comment: @VeXii [`lodash#get`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#get) may return false if the value from the object path is a falsey value. You can use [`lodash#has`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#has) instead.

Answer (score 4):

Lodash has [`_.get`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#get) which allows you to define a keypath towards a nested item in the object. It handles the intermediate checks for you and simply returns either `undefined` or the default value if the key is not found.

```
if(_.get(a, 'b.c') === 'foo')
```

Answer (score 2):

If `a` truly does not exist, you are going to want a *try/catch*, which means you could do:

```
try {
    if (a.b.c === 'foo') {
        // Do stuff.
    }
} catch (ignore) {}
```

Comment: This will catch an error from `a` or `b` not being defined without a way of knowing which was the case. This can be avoided by using `typeof`. Also, this is not shorter than what the OP has already, which is what the question was asking for.

Comment: @ScottMarcus: `typeof a !== "undefined" && a.b && a.b.c === 'foo'` also doesn't tell you if it was `a` or `a.b` that wasn't defined. So what...

Comment: @squint True, but if you break up the tests it can.

Comment: @ScottMarcus, technically it is six characters shorter with the comment removed, but who's counting?

Comment: Yes, true. I guess I was thinking more of lines of code. ;)

Answer (score 1):

Before you worry about making your code shorter, you need to know that your code will throw an error when `a` doesn't exist:

```js
if (a !== undefined && a.b !== undefined && a.b.c === 'foo'){
  console.log("a exists, a.b exists and a.b.c === 'foo'");
}
```

You cannot access a non-existent object without getting an error. So, you need to check the **type** of `a` to see if it is not `"undefined"` (note, the value to check against is a string).

```js
function checkObj(){
  if (typeof a !== "undefined" && a.b && a.b.c === 'foo'){
    console.log("a exists, a has a b property and a.b.c === 'foo'");
  } else {
    console.log("Not all conditions met.");
  }
}

checkObj();  // a doesn't exist --> "Not all conditions met."

var a = {};

checkObj(); // a exists, but b and c don't --> "Not all conditions met."

a.b = {};

checkObj();  // a and b exist but c doesn't --> "Not all conditions met."

a.b.c = "test";

checkObj();  // a, b and c exist, but c has wrong value --> "Not all conditions met."

a.b.c = "foo";

checkObj();  // "a exists, a has a b property and a.b.c === 'foo'"
```